# Drupal - Add image and text under contact form

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to add an image and some text directly under the 'send message' form in Drupal 7.  When I create a new block and add it under the contact form it displays the block far below the form.  I have tried several ways to line up the block so it displays correctly, but no matter what I try it does not appear directly under the 'send message' section.

So now I'm thinking I might be able to simply edit the php file related to the contact form.

So I'm editing contact.pages.inc and I see:

```
$form['actions'] = array('#type' => 'actions');
$form['actions']['submit'] = array(
'#type' => 'submit',
'#value' => t('Send message'),
);
```

Any idea how I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: This is what happens when I try to add a new block under the contact form.  Please see:  http://andtheangelcried.com/images/new_block.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that you avoid hacking core or other modules. From the image you posted, the problem looks like a CSS one. You could place the form and the block that should appear below it in the same region (let's say sidebar 1) and the block on the right in its own region (sidebar 2). Then set width on sidebar 1 and sidebar 2 to 50% and float the sidebars left.